# Highcharts - how to add additional information to chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Example fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-basic/)

source:

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'xxx'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">'+
                    'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value / 1000 +'k';
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    pointStart: 1940,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Inbound',
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6 , 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                    1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                    27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                    26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                    24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                    22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                    10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104 ]
            }, {
                name: 'Outbound',
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null , null , null ,null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
            }]
        });
    });
```

What I need to get is these red / gray rectangles at the top of chart. 
[image]

Is it possible to get it with highcharts? I so, how to do that? Maybe any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `stacking: 'normal'`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/x3zPB/

Comment: I do not think you understand my problem :(

Comment: Right, sorry! I missed note about red bars - unfortunately this is not supported directly. What can you do instead, is to use line series with higher `lineWidth` and disabled markers. See: http://jsfiddle.net/x3zPB/1/

Comment: Thanks Paweł, I'll have to work around the problem in this way

Comment: I've found better solution. http://jsfiddle.net/SineDie/TREwr/3/
Pls tell me how to marge this chart with area chart?

Comment: It's not possible. As you noticed, inverted chart is inverted for all series. You can always draw two different charts.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you need to add new "bar" series to your chart. Then you will be able to add the corret data to those bar series and you will have the expected result.

```
series: [{
            type: 'bar',
                name: 'BarSerie',
                data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
        }]
```