# Highcharts - combine area and columnrange

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I combine these two charts:
[column range - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SineDie/TREwr/3/)
and 
[area](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-basic/)
into one chart with area at the bottom and column range at the top of chart?

[It's an extension of my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588370/)

I've try something like this but it won't work :(
[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wrBq/)

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">'+
                    'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value / 1000 +'k';
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    pointStart: 1940,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            columnrange: {
                grouping: false,
                pointPadding: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    inside: true,
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.y === this.point.low) {
                            var l = '<span style="text-align:left;color:black;margin-left:-' + ((this.point.plotLow - this.point.plotHigh) * 0.55) + 'px">' + this.point.name + ' (' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.point.low) + '-';

                            if (new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) !== new Date(this.point.high).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) l += Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.point.high);
                            l += ')</span>';
                            return l;
                        } else return '';
                    }
                }
            }},
            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USA',
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6 , 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                    1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                    27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                    26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                    24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                    22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                    10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104 ]
            }, {
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USSR/Russia',
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null , null , null ,null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
            },{
            color: 'rgb(100,100,255)',
            pointWidth: 25,
            data: [{
                name: 'Yann B',
                low: Date.UTC(1976, 1, 27, 10, 10),
                high: new Date().valueOf(),
                x: 1 * 10 / 2
            }]
        }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: How would you combine this charts? One chart is inverted, second is default one. All you can do is to create two different charts.

Comment: right, I did not think about it... :\